# Creating separate groups based on dataframe variable

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, pycharm

I have taken 2 variables with +100 values from a pandas dataframe which now looks something like this:

| var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.66 | Yes |
| 0.034 | No |
| 0.422 | Yes |
| 0.934 | No |
| 0.66 | Yes |
| 0.04 | Yes |

I'm trying to perform a Mann whitney U test on these with  the independent groups being:

```
Group1 = "if var1 = "yes" | Group 2 = if var1 = "no"
```

I'm not sure how make these groups fit the Mann whitney U frame?

```
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
U1, p = mannwhitneyu(group1, group2, method="exact")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one shot, groupby var2 and expand the two arrays:

```
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
U1, p = mannwhitneyu(*df.groupby('var2')['var1'].apply(list))
U1, p
```

output: `(4.0, 0.4071687463160714)`

Other option:

```
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
U1, p = mannwhitneyu(df.query('var2 == "yes"')['var1'], df.query('var2 == "no"')['var1'])
U1, p
```

*NB. the `method="exact"` parameter did not work for me, even when manually assigning groups*

Comment: Thank you, I get this error message: 

mannwhitneyu() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

and I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: It looks like you have more than two variables in var2, what is the output of: `df.groupby('var2')['var1'].apply(list)`

Comment: Ah great this works! Thanks. I do notice that for one of the groups it drops a row. So len(var1) is 68 which is great but len(var2) is 457, but it should be 458. Having a look at the df, it has removed the first row?

Comment: I added another option if you have values other than yes/no